# Filter object array where name is union type

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

I have an array i want to filter with typescript, however i can't get the typescript validation side working, i have an array of actions, and i want to filter out the internal actions (see below) - however i cannot tell typescript that the filteredActions array no longer contains internalAction!

Here's what i tried:

```
type ActionName = 'replaceText' | 'replaceImage' | 'internalAction';

interface Action {
  name: ActionName
}
const INTERNAL_ACTIONS = ['internalAction'] as const;
type InternalActions = typeof INTERNAL_ACTIONS[number];

const actions: Action[] = [{
   name: 'replaceText'
}, {
   name: 'replaceImage'
}, {
   name: 'internalAction'
}];
const isInternalAction = (name: ActionName): name is Exclude<ActionName, InternalActions> => name in INTERNAL_SLIDE_ACTIONS;
const filteredActions = actions.filter((action) => !isInternalAction(action.name));
for (const action of filteredActions) {
  if (action.name === 'internalAction') {
    // i'd expect TS to throw an error here as internalAction should never appear
  }
  if (action.name === 'replaceImage') {
    // i'd expect TS to NOT throw an error here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was the filter, I had to rebind the action with the names excluded:

```
const filteredActions = slide.actions.filter((action): action is Action & {
    name: Exclude<ActionName, InternalActions>
} => typeof INTERNAL_ACTIONS.find(i => i === action.name) === 'undefined');
```

This way each action after filtering has the correct typings

Comment: Btw it is okay to do without `Omit<>` in this case because the intersection operator `&` will pick the common options of `name` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in `isInternalAction` arrow function.

in order to check if an element in an array in typescript you cannot use [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), but you can use: [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (maybe there is other options but these are on the top of my head)

so I would change your code to for example:

```
type ActionName = 'replaceText' | 'replaceImage' | 'internalAction';

interface Action {
  name: ActionName
}
const INTERNAL_ACTIONS: readonly ActionName[] = ['internalAction'] as const;
type InternalActions = typeof INTERNAL_ACTIONS[number];

const actions: Action[] = [{
  name: 'replaceText'
}, {
  name: 'replaceImage'
}, {
  name: 'internalAction'
}];

// use includes to check if element exists in an array
const isInternalAction = (name: ActionName): boolean => INTERNAL_ACTIONS.includes(name);
const filteredActions = actions.filter((action) => !isInternalAction(action.name));

console.log(filteredActions)
```

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYDkCGBbaBeKAcgCcIwAbTOCAFQgA9hCoAfI0iqiASW0wHMIzNoUSpgEYqkzl4SNIQDcAKGViJxAGZdYCFKigBvZVCjTcALl3yMOCMoC%20yuGgDOwKN3Q0AogCV0GAAZAH0YAGEabgB5dABlK1JMABM0chBrfSxcAG0AXSgCHNFxSWlZPQUCzFcoF1R3FVBIT1KpGTl9WoJmiGRNT29-QNCIqNi4nNQAV2wAI0k8lWc3DyobVytOtHzCqBzjU3MIKxIySmo6RkJHABojEzM7U44Lnj5BG4d7w6fLInUZQ6lVQXyWKwaHkQrm4bXK2wMBAAFMctiDshAAJRWObIZDkCCYREAPkGvgCwTCkRi8QAdGI4ORpskIK4UXZMSp6u4oJpEOQNBBkgjulB1l1aXyBZIkUjxWhMYVSQBCaGwjTwkFykG046Yzmqbn4iC08jIfhIqWC4Ug1yYoA) you can find and run the snippet above in a ts-playground

Comment: That was my bad, mis typed! but this doesn't solve the typescript validation as filteredActions[0].name is still the type of ActionName